# Invalid TxHash 0x2d03f2319fdd3e122379164e79a1dceae991f525 entered

Tags: etherscan

I bought 0.09 ETH via remitano today . It has been 2-3 hours , but I haven't received ETH yet in my binance ETH account .
[image]

The transaction summary on remitano shows , that the ETH was indeed sent to the same address.
[image]

But when I check on etherscan.io , I get an erro[image]

Not sure why this error is there and what it means. This was my first ETH transaction. Can anybody please help ?

Comment: Same problem here, when I tried to track my TXID on etherscan, it is nothing. Could someone please advise ? TXID: 0x67c8b0b91db42d3184ef24cf6c6497295a02f113f0b3e4dad20b79529a86bbd4 Thank you

Comment: You have to ask to both exchange's support teams, there's nothing else you can do about it. If you have a transaction id you can take a look at etherscan or any block explorer.

Comment: Hi Ismael, the transaction id is 0x186bc6af5ee6defdcf98e597be5fcd6bdc2ae3695d70f1eb2cba94ebe209e861. But on etherscan.io it says "Sorry, we are unable to locate this Transaction Hash" . Does that mean it has not yet been transferred from remitano yet ?

Answer (score 1):

`0x2d03f2319fdd3e122379164e79a1dceae991f525` isn't a transaction hash; it's an address.

But https://etherscan.io/address/0x2d03f2319fdd3e122379164e79a1dceae991f525 shows no ether in that account and no pending transactions. It doesn't look like ether was sent to you at all.

I'm unfamiliar with Remitano or how it works. You'll need to contact them to find out what went wrong.